# Getting Runtime error for cross entropy. What should be changed and why it is coming

Tags: python, pytorch

I am testing on movie lens data set. I have tried increasing the output in nn.linear(n_act,5) to n_act,10 but nothing is working

The code is below and the error is afterwards

```
dls=CollabDataLoaders.from_df(ratings,item_name='Title',bs=64)

class deeplearn(Module):
    def __init__(self,user_size,movie_size,n_act=50,y_range=(0,5.5)):
        self.user_factors=create_params(user_size)
        self.movie_factors=create_params(movie_size)
        self.layers=nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Linear(user_size[1]+movie_size[1],n_act),
                    nn.ReLU(),
                    nn.Linear(n_act,5)
        )
        self.y_range=y_range
        
    def forward(self,x):
        embs=self.user_factors[x[:,0]],self.movie_factors[x[:,1]]
        x1=self.layers(torch.cat(embs,dim=1))
        return sigmoid_range(x1,*self.y_range)

embs=get_emb_sz(dls)        
n_users=6041
n_movies=3707

model = deeplearn(*embs)
learn3 = Learner(dls, model, loss_func=CrossEntropyLossFlat)
learn3.fit_one_cycle(5, 5e-3, wd=0.01)
```

After executing getting
RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
nvs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/_reduction.py in legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce, emit_warning)
     35         reduce = True
     36 
---> 37     if size_average and reduce:
     38         ret = 'mean'
     39     elif reduce:

RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you tell me more which information should I provide

Comment: A small, complete example that can be run to observe the error. Also, is that the entire error trace?

Answer (score 0):

Try use value with CrossEntropy,

```
loss = CrossEntropyLossFlat 
learn3 = Learner(dls, model, loss_func=loss)
```

It's work for me.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. If you take some time to explain _why_ this works, it would improve the quality of your answer.